# Is a self-wormhole possible?

Tags: general-relativity, wormholes

If we think of a wormhole as two blackholes where points on each horizon are identified. Should a "self-wormhole" not also be possible?

e.g. where opposite points on the event horizon are identified?

So if you go in one side you emerge on the other side instantaneously. (Not that this is how wormholes work).

so instead of the topology being like a tube it would be like a cross-cap.

I can't see any reason why this shouldn't also be a solution of Einstein's equations.

Comment: You can identify the wormhole surfaces how you wish, although be aware that the resulting spacetime may not be orientable with some identifications. And it is doubtful that spacetime can be non-orientable.

Comment: GR doesn't make any requirements about the topology of spacetime, so as long as the topology you propose is consistent with the spacetime curvature, you're describing a solution. Note that this doesn't say anything about whether such a wormhole is stable, traversible, or can be formed from gravitational collapse or without exotic matter. Also, I wouldn't describe any of this in terms of black holes or event horizons.

Comment: The usual concern about orientability is that a realistic spacetime should be a spin manifold, so that it is possible to describe fermions on it. But other than that yes, it is certainly a solution (usually called non-orientable wormholes or Alice handles)

Comment: @Slerah That's interesting about the orientation. I think the same would apply to a 'self-wormhole'. I think you would come out backwards and mirror reflected.

Comment: I thought about giving a full answer, and I might later, but the open ended nature of this is such that a full answer can lead to serious down votes. This idea is in some ways similar to Susskind's ER = EPR hypothesis of assigning early Hawking radiation with states near the horizon. This is a way of avoiding the quantum monogamy violation.